# How to make a subclass implement an interface?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface, subclass

I have created a class and a subclass. I also have an interface in the parent class. How can I make the child class implement the interface?

The code is:

```
class Car
{ 
    public interface ISmth
    {
        void MyMethod();
    }
}
class MyCar : Car
{ 
    //implement the interface 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how your code should probably be laid out.

```
public interface ISmth
{
    void MyMethod();
}

class Car
{
}

class MyCar : Car, ISmth
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a reason to nest `ISmth` in `Car`, but if you do have one you certainly could do it.

Comment: I think this doesn't enforce `MyCar` to implement `MyMethod` in cases where `Car` happens to implement `MyMethod`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare MyCar like that:

```
class MyCar: Car, Car.ISmth {}
```