# Implement interface with subclassed properties

Tags: c#

Given the interface

```
public interface baseInterface {
    IList<double> listProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to implement the interface with a property as a subclass of the property type as per the following example?

```
public class newClass : baseInterface
{
    public List<double> listProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @HardikMasalawala no OP's trying to expose `IList` on a base interface and `List` on the derived class.

Comment: @ParrishHusband My interface defines a contract between two different systems that are maintained by different people. I would actually like to define the interface as IEnumerable<double> and then let the people who are implementing the classes have the freedom to use a concrete class like list in their implementation.

Comment: @Sudsy - `listProperty` is *settable*. What happens when someone assigns some *completely* different enumerable object to it when accessing it via the interface? (Ignoring for the time being that settable collection/enumerable properties is almost always a bad idea anyway)

Comment: What Damien said: The code from your question cannot be valid because if you have an instance of your class inside a variable of type of the interface, that is `baseInterface x = new newClass();`; then `x.listProperty = SomeAlternativeIListOfDouble;` will try to assign an `IList<double>` which is not a `List<double>`, to a concrete property in the class whose type _is_ `List<double>`.

Comment: I see what you are saying. It seemed so simple to me when I wrote the question, but of course it can't work. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Please check Below link it should be solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663209/how-to-make-a-subclass-implement-an-interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two approaches you could look at.

(1) You would have to use an explicit implementation to make it work:

```
public interface BaseInterface
{
    IList<double> ListProperty { get; set; }
}

public class NewClass : BaseInterface
{
    public List<double> ListProperty { get; set; }

    IList<double> BaseInterface.ListProperty
    {
        get => this.ListProperty;
        set => this.ListProperty = value.ToList();
    }
}
```

(2) Use generics to allow for a subclass to be used:

```
public interface BaseInterface<L, T> where L : IList<T>
{
    L ListProperty { get; set; }
}

public class NewClass : BaseInterface<List<double>, double>
{
    public List<double> ListProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Both of these allow you to have a `public List<double> ListProperty { get; set; }` in `NewClass`.

Comment: Of course, be aware that with `.ToList()` a shallow _clone_ of the given `IList<>` is created. Later changes (such as `IList<>.Add`) to the instance that was used when setting, will not be reflected in the clone held by the class. So in that way, setting the property through the interface (the explicit interface implementation) is different semantically from setting the `public` property of the class.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make interface generic.

```
public interface baseInterface <T> where T : IEnumerable<double>
    {
        T Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class derivedInterface : baseInterface <List<double>>
    {
        private List<double> m_Data = new List<double>();
        public List<double> Data { get { return m_Data; } 
        set { this.m_MyData = value; }}
    }
```